# LINQ - GROUP BY IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq

Using LINQ, how can I group this list results by **firstThree**?  My group method is not working.

```
    var findOtherZipCodes = (from z in zipCodes                                    
                                 from results in zipFirstThree
                                 where (results.region.ToUpper() == z.City
                                 && results.state == z.State)   
                                select new ZipCodeFirstThree
                                {
                                    region = z.City,
                                    state = z.State,
                                    firstThree = z.ZipCode1.ToString().Substring(0, 3),
                                    zipCode = z.ZipCode1.ToString()
                                }).ToList();

   findOtherZipCodes.GroupBy(x => x.firstThree).ToList();

        foreach (var item in findOtherZipCodes) {
            Console.WriteLine(item.region + " " + item.firstThree + " " + item.zipCode);
            Thread.Sleep(500);


        }
```

Comment: Both of the calls to `ToList` in your code are accomplishing nothing.  There is no need for you to use that method at all to perform this query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your `GroupBy` is not working is that you are ignoring its results. It should be like this:

```
var groups = findOtherZipCodes.GroupBy(x => x.firstThree).ToList();
```

Change the `foreach` loop like this to complete the fix:

```
foreach (var group in groups) {
    var firstInGroup = group.First();    
    Console.WriteLine(firstInGroup.region + " " + group.Key + " " + firstInGroup.zipCode);
    Thread.Sleep(500);
}
```

Comment: Your solution helped me accomplish the desired grouping, thank you very much sir.